# gamecenter bot 5005 NO SUCH PLAYER ID

Tags: ios, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

Is it possible to create a turn-based match where players would verse specific 'machine user accounts' in game-center?

I'm making a turn-based game and wanting to allow the end-user to play against the machine. Therefore I created a game center account for my machine.

In my GKTurnBasedMatch, I have my GKTurnBasedParticipant in

```
_match.participants
```

iterating through all participants, i see the machine player ID is:

```
_match.currentParticipant.player.playerID
8027277420
```

I also tried putting in the email address for live and sandbox accounts: AppEnemy1Sand@gmail.com and AppEnemy1@gmail.com

**I am running on simulator**

However when I request to start a match, where the participant is my machine, with

```
-(void) playComputerWithNumberOfEnemiesEqualTo:(int) numberOfEnemies
{   
  if(numberOfEnemies > 0 && numberOfEnemies <= 3)
  {
    if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated)
    {
      [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:@[@"AppEnemy1Sand@gmail.com"] withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<GKPlayer *> * _Nullable players, NSError * _Nullable error)
      {
        NSLog(@"players %@",players);
        NSLog(@"EE %@",error);
      }];
    }
 }
```

}

The error reads:

```
Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=8 "The requested operation could not be completed because the player is invalid." UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5005, NSUnderlyingError=0x7896f570 {Error Domain=GKServerErrorDomain Code=5005 "status = 5005, NO SUCH PLAYER ID" UserInfo={GKServerStatusCode=5005, NSLocalizedFailureReason=status = 5005, NO SUCH PLAYER ID}}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you invite players, including the "machine player"? I

Comment: Hi @Thunk the sandbox account is: AppEnemy1Sand@gmail.com. I updated the sourcecode to include some of the surrounding code